# Is it possible to stream multiple channels of u-law audio over RTP?

Tags: java, audio, rtp, mu-law

I'm currently recording audio with 8000 samples per second, 8 bits per sample, and one channel and sending them to another machine using RTP.

Would I create a two-channel buffer consisting of u-law audio before sending an RTP packet? Something like this:

```
[uLawLeftEarSample0][uLawRightEarSample0][uLawLeftEarSample1][uLawRightEarSample1][uLawLeftEarSample2][uLawRightEarSample2]...[uLawLeftEarSample8000][uLawRightEarSample8000]
```

Would something like this be RFC-compliant?

Answer (score 0):

When testing my code with VLC as the player, the "two-channel" u-law rtp payload would be read as if it was mono. It looks like I'll have to use a profile that supports two-channels such as MP3 or WAV. More [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTP_audio_video_profile).